# Why does it write with "ed"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Why does it always write like this? What if you write without "ed"? What is the rule for this?

> I love to be lov**ed** by you / I love to be lov**e** by you.
>
> I like to be lik**ed** by you / I like to be lik**e** by you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The passive in English is **always**, whatever the tense, conveyed by the so-called past participle, usually following a part of "be". (Colloquially, it can follow a part of "get" instead"):

> He is heard.
>
> He will be heard.
>
> He got heard.

Most verbs form their past participle with *-ed*: *loved*, *liked*, *appreciated*, *angered*, *buried*, *created*. Some form it in other ways: *seen*, *broken*, *taken*, *hit*, *heard*.

To form an infinitive of the passive, it is the auxiliary ("be" or "get") that is in infinitive form: *to be seen*; *to get eaten*.

*To be love* is not grammatical (unless you are using the noun "love" rather than the verb: *It seems to be love between them*.)